# iOS Facebook sdk 4.0 share an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to share an image using the new facebook sdk 4.0.
I'm using the same code in the facebook example but I'm getting this exception when I try to present the `FBSDKShareDialog`.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "SELF NOT NULL"'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b782a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x000000010b35abb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   Foundation
>   0x000000010aca097d _qfqp2_performParsing + 8495   3   Foundation
>   0x000000010ac9e7e6 +[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:arguments:] + 46
>     4   Foundation                          0x000000010ac9e7a0
>   +[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:] + 142     5   PhotoGunShot                        0x0000000107f1a4fc -[FBSDKShareDialog
>   _showShareSheetWithCanShowError:validationError:] + 653   6   PhotoGunShot                        0x0000000107f18f7b
>   -[FBSDKShareDialog show] + 147

Here is the code

```
- (UIAlertAction*) createActionForFacebookWithMediaPath:(NSString*) path andMediaType:(MediaType) mediaType {
    NSString * mediaName = mediaType == kMediaTypeImage ? NSLocalizedString(@"KEY_IMAGE", nil) : NSLocalizedString(@"KEY_VIDEO", nil);
    UIAlertAction* facebookAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",NSLocalizedString(@"KEY_SHARE_YOUR", nil),mediaName] style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                              NSObject<FBSDKSharingContent> * content = nil;
                                                              if (mediaType == kMediaTypeImage) {
                                                                  NSURL * fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
                                                                  FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
                                                                  photo.imageURL = fileURL;
//                                                                  photo.userGenerated = YES;
                                                                  FBSDKSharePhotoContent * photoContent = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
                                                                  photoContent.photos = @[photo];
                                                                  content = photoContent;
                                                              }
                                                              else if (mediaType == kMediaTypeVideo) {
                                                                  NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

                                                                  FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
                                                                  video.videoURL = videoURL;
                                                                  FBSDKShareVideoContent * videoContent = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
                                                                  videoContent.video = video;
                                                                  content = videoContent;
                                                              }
                                                                  [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                                                                               withContent:content
                                                                                                  delegate:nil];

                                                          }];
    return facebookAction;

}
- (UIAlertAction*) createActionForCameraRollWithMediaPath:(NSString*) path andMediaType:(MediaType) mediaType {
    return nil;

}
- (void) showShareOptionsForMediaPath:(NSString*)path {
    UIAlertController * alertControl =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"KEY_SHARE_TITLE", nil) message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    UIAlertAction * cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"KEY_CANCEL", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:NULL];
    [alertControl addAction:cancelAction];
    MediaType mediaType = [self checkMediaTypeAtPath:path];
    switch (mediaType) {
        case kMediaTypeImage:
        {
            UIAlertAction * fbAction =[self createActionForFacebookWithMediaPath:path andMediaType:kMediaTypeImage];
            [alertControl addAction:fbAction];
        }
            break;
        case kMediaTypeVideo:
        {
            UIAlertAction * fbAction =[self createActionForFacebookWithMediaPath:path andMediaType:kMediaTypeVideo];
            [alertControl addAction:fbAction];

        }
            break;
        case kMediaTypeUnknown:
        {
            //EXCEPTION
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self presentViewController:alertControl animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

First I create an UIAlertController that shows the share options, and add the relative `UIAlertAction`, the exception is generated when I call the share dialog.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I've filed a bug it seems to be a know issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue will be fixed in the next SDK release.

Apparently you can remove the below line from FBSDKShareDialog and build the framework from source to work around it.
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareDialog.m#L442

You can view the bug that Andrea filed , here : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/964300063610778/